# apt autoremove deleted software in use

Tags: apt, 20.04

The first thing I realized after running `apt autoremove` and rebooting was that DockX no longer starts. A glance at `/var/log/apt/term.log` told me that the packages were indeed eradicated despite being in use right at the moment it happened:

```
Removing dockbarx (0.93+git20190103-1~ppa3) ...
Removing dockbarx-applet-appindicator (0.93+git20190103-1~ppa3) ...
Removing dockbarx-applet-clock (0.93+git20190103-1~ppa3) ...
Removing dockbarx-applet-hello-world (0.93+git20190103-1~ppa3) ...
Removing dockbarx-applet-volume-control (0.93+git20190103-1~ppa3) ...
Removing dockbarx-dockx (0.93+git20190103-1~ppa3) ...
```

My question is: Why did `apt` decide to remove these packages and how can I prevent this behaviour in the future?

**Update**

It was suggested that the packages were removed because they were dependencies of some other, already removed packages. This is not the case. I rolled back the VM anyway and now I can look at the state before the event, using `dockbarx` as an example:

```
~$ apt-rdepends -r dockbarx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
dockbarx
~$
```

This is it. There are no packages dependent on `dockbarx`.

I suspect the situation is somehow related to the fact that I installed these packages from a PPA that is no longer connected. Could there be a link?

**Update 2**

Checked the logs manually to find out that the `dockbarx` package was installed as a dependency of `xfce4-dockbarx-plugin`, a package my system is no longer aware of - most likely because of the disconnected PPA:

```
~$ apt show xfce4-dockbarx-plugin
N: Unable to locate package xfce4-dockbarx-plugin
N: Unable to locate package xfce4-dockbarx-plugin
E: No packages found
```

Which is why `apt-rdepends` gives wrong output for `dockbarx`. Overall, the answer below is correct and I am accepting it.

This was quite a detective story.

Comment: Good detective work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's all about apt-marking**

Any package that is not a automatically-installed dependency (apt-marked 'auto') dependency of a specified package (apt-marked 'manual') is eligible for autoremoval.

Example:

`sudo apt install foo bar`

- SPECIFIED packages (foo, bar) will be marked **manual**
- All unspecified dependencies (libfoo1, baz) will be apt-marked **auto**

Apparently, you removed whatever 'manual' package required those 'auto' dependencies.

- Apt does not know or care that specific software is *in use*. It's not especially intelligent, and definitely not magical.

**In order to prevent autoremoval of a package**, simply ensure that the package has an apt-marking of 'manual.'

```
apt-mark showauto                    // List the packages apt-marked 'auto'
                                     // Listing does not require sudo 
                                     // It's a long list

sudo apt-mark manual <package_name>  // Change a package from 'auto' to 'manual'
```

Comment: Does not seem to be the case. Using the `dockbarx` package as an example, there are no packages depending on it according to common sense and `apt-rdepends` both. Will update my question to clarify this.

Comment: Okay, you were correct in the end. See the final update to my question for the full story. ))